# sublime text black background

Tags: sublime-text

`Build 4143` 
`6.3.2-arch1-1`

All the 'dark' options for color scheme offer a brown background. I want a black background.

I have tried this in preferences/settings:

```
{
"theme": "Default.sublime-theme",
"color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.sublime-color-scheme",
"theme_default_small_tabs": true,
"theme_default_bg": "0,0,0",
"theme_default_fg": "255,255,255"
}
```

Restarted sublime and I still have brown background.